# How to deploy migrations which remove models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, database-migration

I'm refactoring a large Rails application, and making considerable changes to a pretty arcane database structure. This has included dropping a lot of tables and models, putting the data into other parts of the database.

To make the situation clearer, let's say I'm moving data from the unnecessary `user_level` table into the `user` table. What I've done so far is:

- Create a migration which adds an `access_level` column to the `user` table, and then does something like:

  User.all.each do |u|
     u.access_level = u.user_level.level
  end
- Run that migration. Check it into git.
- Remove the `user_level` model and the association from `user.rb`. Check that into git.
- Create a migration which drops the `user_level` table. Run that and check it into git.

This works beautifully in development but I don't know how to deploy it to the production server. Currently our rather inelegant deployment procedure is to run `git pull` on the server, then do any `db:migrate`s or similar that are needed. But if we do this, when we `git pull` to update the code to head and then try to migrate, the `UserLevel` model isn't there any more and so `u.user_level.level` will fail. (I'm open to using something like Capistrano, but I don't know if that would help in this situation either.)

If there was a way to checkout every git commit in turn and run `db:migrate` after each one, it would all work perfectly, but I don't know how to do that, and I'm sure this must be a solved problem anyway. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Because the code update is running before the migration during deployment, the models you deleted are not existing anymore.

I think you can use pure sql command instead of the ruby code `User.all.each do |u| u.access_level = u.user_level.level end`.

Comment: This would work fine in a simple case such as the example. In a more complex case (which is unfortunately what I'm dealing with) I need to use some of the old model's methods to massage the data into a serialisable format - sorry, should have mentioned this. (I am changing thirty tables worth of technical specification data *which never changes* into a JSON document and shoving that into a column. Serializing all the associations into a single document takes a bit of work, and can't be done in pure SQL. Well, I'm sure it can be done, but I shudder to think...)

Comment: Oh, I see. I don't know how to change the deployment flow either. I would try to create another branch and cherry-pick the commits without the delete parts, then use this branch to do deployment(only for db). The migration should work in the temporary branch. After that, deploy again with the master branch to delete the models.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`git checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) to grab the code for a given commit. E.g:

```
git checkout 4ddcd26652a9516aecff7a7e17f4c324bdb8f6dd
```

Where `4ddcd26652a9516aecff7a7e17f4c324bdb8f6dd` would be the commit hash.

So, for your case, you can perform the `git pull` followed by a `git checkout` for a specific commit.  After running the migration, you can move back to master.

Although, your best bet for the future is to avoid using models (or any other external dependencies) directly in migration files.  One way is to define the model inside of the migration (I am just guessing what the model might look like):

```
class AddAccessLevelToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  class UserLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
  end

  def up
    add_column :users, :access_level, :string
    UserLevel.each do |user_level|
      user = user_level.user
      user.access_level = user_level.access_level
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :access_level
  end
end
```

You can also simply write SQL within the migration file itself.  Read more about it via [Change Migrations like a Boss](http://railsguides.net/2014/01/30/change-data-in-migrations-like-a-boss/) from Andrey Koleshko.

Removing the dependency to the model will prevent issues with people trying to pull down the application and run all of the migrations from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing all the refactoring but **not** dropping the models or the underlying table right away? Do that in a separate follow-up refactoring.